# How to access context init parameters from a PreProcessInterceptor?

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am inside a RESTEasy [PreProcessInterceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/interception/PreProcessInterceptor.html) and need to access a parameter I've configured in my WAR's web.xml (either as an `init-param` in the servlet definition of the RestEasy servlet - as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html) - or as a `context-param`).

How do I achieve that?

Alternatively, is there some other place where I should be configuring parameters that I need to be made available to my interceptors at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the following. In the past I had my [PreProcessorInterceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/interception/PreProcessInterceptor.html) defined in the WAR's `web.xml` as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>my.package.MyPreProcessorInterceptor</param-value>        
</context-param>
```

I now moved it away from the `web.xml` and placed it inside my [Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) as follows:

```
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public JaxRsApplication(@Context ServletContext servletContext) {
        Assert.assertNotNull(servletContext);
        singletons.add( new MyPreProcessorInterceptor(servletContext) );        
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```